# Microsoft Code Connect with Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

A few weeks ago, I installed Code Connection on my Win 10 laptop, connected to Minecraft, and played around with the tutorials for a while. Now, when I try to use Code Connection, Minecraft just says "can't connect to server". My network has not changed -- and in any case, I'm connecting to localhost. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually using localhost as the hostname for the websocket connect in bedrock? My understanding is that UWP apps (Win10 store apps) actually aren't allowed to connect over the localhost/loopback interface. For this reason, the Code Connection app should be giving you an address that's one of your actual IPs on your box. If it's not, something seems off to me.